# Unable to addView because of unknown parent?

Tags: java, android, parent-child

I am trying to create a table. The number of rows however will vary each time the app is loaded so i add them programatically. Rows have their own xml layout aside from the mainLayout. However when trying to add rows to the tableview in the mainlayout i get an error (tableLayou.addView(row)). here is my code:

```
private void makeTable() {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TableRow row;
    AutofitTextView textView;
    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            (float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int width = (configuration.screenWidthDp/8)*dip;
    int height = (configuration.screenHeightDp/10)*dip;
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    for (int i = 0; i<rowss.size();i++) {

        row =(TableRow) v.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(rowss.get(i));
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
            AutofitTextView textView1 = (AutofitTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
            textView1.setText(s.next());
        }

        tableLayout.addView(row);

    }

}
```

Row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/reason"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/block"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/carrier"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/inventory"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




</TableRow>
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_main">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4654)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4490)
                                                                                       at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:426)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4431)
                                                                                       at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:408)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4404)
                                                                                       at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:399)
                                                                                       at com.intellidev.earlyupgradepicklist.MainActivity.makeTable(MainActivity.java:460)
                                                                                       at com.intellidev.earlyupgradepicklist.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                                       at com.intellidev.earlyupgradepicklist.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:411)
                                                                                       at com.intellidev.earlyupgradepicklist.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:331)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. What is your goal here? You wish to use the TableLayout as a List? If so, you could and should use a ListView for the purpose.

> The point of using ListView is to be able to scale to larger data sets
>   by not having to create and layout views for all of the items
>   up-front.

The problem at the moment is that **everytime you run the cycle, you keep adding the same object** to the TableLayout

```
row =(TableRow) v.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
...        
tableLayout.addView(row);
```

and since it already exists, it throws the 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first'
What you can do is have an ArrayAdapter that contains all the TableRow views that you create, and add them like this :

```
int count = adapter.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    tableLayout.addView(createTableRow(adapter.getItem(i)); // or tableLayout.addView(adapter.getView(i, null, tableLayout));
}
```

Overall, your table_row.xml seems like an entry to a list where you have a manufacturer, an id, etc.
You could switch the TableLayout for a ListView (which is the proper element to deal with nested data in rows)

[You can find documentation for the ListView here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)
and 
[Check this example for a ListView with CustomAdapter](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Either way, I'll be glad to help you with it.
Regards,